# Collection of Collections VS Dictionary of Collections in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Situation:
I need to pass in a collection of objects, and then group them. I am aware that I can use LINQ for that.

However, if I was to do it myself, **is there any preference between having my method return Collection of Collections VS Dictionary of Collections?** I am aware that Dictionary is also a collection, but it introduces the key parameter.

- Intended use for the object returned is to display in groups using For Each statement.
- Average number in original collection is somewhere around 20, so performance is not an issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dictionary is probably the way to go. How are you grouping them(i.e. might be easier to say if you give us the structure of your objects)?

Comment: *Intended use for the object returned is to display in groups using For Each statement.* Will you need to deal with grouping the items? Or are they already returning grouped?

Comment: If you need to access a specific collection at any time, i'd recommand the dictionary, if not, you don't need to have a key, and a collection of collections would be enough

Comment: The key benefit of a dictionary is that it provides fast access to particular items based on a key value. If you're not going to be looking up items this way, and instead just iterating through the collection, I'm not sure why you'd use a dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries have more overhead, so if all you are going to do with the collections is loop through them and you don't need to search for individual groups, I'd go with the collection of collections.

Comment: @FrancineDeGroodTaylor please don't post things like that, Dictionary is actually faster than List because its a hash table and has O(1) lookup where a List is O(n) when searching by a key. http://net-informations.com/faq/general/dictionary-list.htm

Comment: @RonBeyer It is faster when you want to get a specific item. If you're going to iterate through all the values, you'll be in O(n) in both cases.... Or i missed something

Comment: I am planing to simply display the groups with items inside them. No need to accessing single items at a time.

Comment: Right, so if you could use a dictionary (where later the key is useful) then its advantageous to put it in a dictionary because there is no performance loss (or gain) when iterating, but when searching Dictionary[item] is a lot faster than List.Contains(item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the obvious decision point of whether or not you need to be able to index into the outer collection by some criteria(as a Dictionary would provide) is just generally how much information you need on each outer item.

At one end of the spectrum is each outer item has no metadata connected to it.  Each item in the outer list is just a collection, and there is no identifying information.  If for example, you grouped a list of students by what dorm they lived in, as you iterated through the lists, you would know that all of this group of students belong to the same dorm, but you have no idea which dorm that is based solely on your list of lists.

The middle of the spectrum is a dictionary with a primitive key. You now have on piece of information for each nested list, the KeyValuePair Key.  This key might be some sort of unique ID identifying the dorm.

The other end of the spectrum is unlimited metadata.  You define a class for the items in the outer list, and a property of that item is a collection:

```
class Dorm {

  public int DormID {get;set;}
  public string DormName {get;set;}
  public Gender DormPermittedGender {get;set;}
  public List<Person> Students {get;set;}
}

class Person {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Gender Gender {get;set;}
  public int Age{get;set;}
}

///...
List<Dorm> dorms = db.Dorms.Select(d=> 
  new Dorm {
     DormId = d.Id,
     DormName = d.Name,
     DormPermittedGender = d.PermittedGender,
     Students = d.StudentsResiding
  }
)

foreach(Dorm dorm in dorms)
{
   foreach(Person student in dorm.Students)
   {
      Console.Writeline(student.Name + " lives in " + dorm.DormName);
   }
}
```

Notice how readable that foreach is.  No mysterious keys.

Now Dictionary's are actually capable of this, as you can have complex objects as a Key, but it is not as organized.  If the situation calls for it, strongly typed objects will better represent the relationship.

Overuse of List of Lists or Dictionaries can make code difficult to read, as there are no self describing property names.  You come across some old code and you have to jump around to find where a Dictionary was first assigned to determine the meaning of the Key, because all you have is the type is an `int` which conveys no semantics.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments :

- If you do need to lookup a specific item : **Dictionary** => Because the lookup time is **O(1)**
- If you only need to iterate through all the items : Both will do, since the lookup time will be **O(n)** in both case

Comment: So seems to me Dictionary is a better choice, because if I do ever need to extend my system and actually look up 1 item at a time, it will be more efficient, is that correct?

Comment: If you feel you'll need the feature in the future, yes.

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary` is almost certainly the wrong way to go if you want to present the contents to the user, and you say you do. A `Dictionary` has no predictable order. Showing the items in a `Dictionary` in the order you retrieve them from that `Dictionary` is meaningless.

A `SortedDictionary` or a `SortedList`, always sorted by key value, might be appropriate if the order of the keys matches the intended order of the items.

But otherwise, just use a regular array/`List`/`Collection` in which you can manually put the items in exactly the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have posted a rather vague question, but let's run with it and make it a bit more concrete. Let's suppose you have a collection of this class:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

And you have a method that groups this (and optionally filters, ... does other stuff), like this:

```
public RETURNTYPE ProcessItemGroupedByOrderDate(IEnumerable<MyItem> items);
```

That is supposed to group by the `OrderDate` property.

And your question is:

> Is there any preference between having my method return Collection of
>   Collections VS Dictionary of Collections? Intended use for the object
>   returned is to display in groups using For Each statement.

I.e. should `RETURNTYPE` be

- `IDictionary<DateTime, ICollection<MyItem>>` or
- `ICollection<ICollection<MyItem>>`

where `ICollection` represents any suitable type of collection (`IEnumerable`, `IList`, ...).

My answer would be: let the **client** decide. If you return a grouping, let the return type be just that:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, MyItem>>
```